# What's going on in this visual render of an attacker and defender in Information Security?

Tags: countermeasure

I'm self taught programmer and therefore an info security enthusiast, and [I saw this video but I dont quite understand what's going on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7DKSao0ndI).Can someone please explain what's happenning, step by step in this video, which claims to be a rendered simulation of a computer program fending off a hacker?

[image]

I suppose my question is first "Is this an accurate representation of automated defense?" and then if so "What is happening exactly?"

Answer (score 2):

This is a DDoS attack.

The purple bubbles are infected computers. By having thousands of infected computers, an hacker can simply force them to attack a target. This kind of attack means that there will be so many requests to a single server that he cannot handle with them all, making the server crash or simple not responding for a while.

To understand what is the definition of a DDoS attack i just copy a simple definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)

> In computing, a denial-of-service (DoS) attack is an attempt to make a machine or network resource unavailable to its intended users, such as to temporarily or indefinitely interrupt or suspend services of a host connected to the Internet. A distributed denial-of-service (DDoS) is where the attack source is more than one–and often thousands of-unique IP addresses.

The green bubbles are honeypots. The honeypot is just a simple "system" on the network that will provide some distraction to the hacker.

This means that instead of attacking the correct target, for example an webserver, the hacker will be attacking an honeypot, meaning that the real server don't have to handle with all the requests and the attack will not have any real impact.

The red and grey bubles, i think, that are really server responses.

Comment: Yeah, later on it did eventually look like a potential DDoS attack, but I'm not quite sure since the video is so blurry, and the linked webpage is not available. I think we can only guess what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm viewing this right, then this is basically a honeypot setup to detect malicious users on the network (incoming and outgoing connections) and blacklist their IP / browser fingerprint.

1. **The green circles** are honeypots. A `honeypot` may send out "signals" to make hackers on the network aware of their presence, or they may just be lying dormant waiting for someone to trigger them. Hackers who are inside the network attempt to access the honeypot. Since nobody on the network should ever have a legitimate reason to access the honeypot, it automatically adds that IP address / user (even if local) to the firewall and blocks them.

   Now, honeypots don't actively seek out targets like shown in the video. It isn't that much like an immune system. In fact, a better representation would be the honeypots attracting the scans like a magnet (both incoming and outgoing), and blocking the transfer of data to/fro when triggered. (**Thanks, @Iszi**)

   Finding ways around honeypots *can* be trivial with the correct skill set. For example, you use a proxy IP and connect to a network. When you have a connection established, you can begin scanning the network. If you get shut out as soon as you attempt to access X resource, that *can* be correctly identified as a honeypot. On your next attack, you can exclude those resources.

   Adding a little randomization by putting many different honeypots, and randomly shutting out attackers depending on some kind of central algorithm can really obfuscate this process and make it incredibly difficult to map out the correct honeypot responses. In general, though, if you have access to these honeypots, and there's nothing useful on them, you could presume they're a honeypot and move on, then start the search again with a different proxy. 
   To an untrained IT security professional who doesn't realize the purpose of a honeypot, they might just block the connection and do a "YES! I stopped the haxor!" hand move. But it could simply be part of an attack to determine what is right, and what isn't.

   Alternatively, an attacker may already know which specific resources to access, making a honeypot moot.

   However, it can be an effective countermeasure to block a local user from accessing anything on the local network *if* that user triggers the honeypot, even if they're part of the same network. The reason for this is that the user account may be compromised, and may be attempting to access resources they shouldn't be. That user may have access to plenty of critical infrastructure, but should still never attempt to access the honeypots.
2. **The Purple Circles** are users. When potentially malicious IP addresses are blocked, the honeypot aims to prevent user data from getting out, coming in, or both. Unless the honeypot(s) detected rogue access earlier and shut down the user, then they won't work if the attacker already knows what to access, or never touches the honeypots.
3. **The tiny red and white circles** which are attacking green and purple dots are malicious individuals / programs / whatever.

A honeypot could be *anything*. It could be something set up to take default logins, it could be a dormant networked device resource, fake files, fake databases - anything to trick someone into thinking it's useful, and perhaps reverse-engineer what the attacker is doing. It could even be an infected pdf file that tricks the attacker into executing on their own machine when opening it.

Essentially, this video is a way of trying to visually represent what's going on with the honeypot / IDS and Firewall.